# How to execute trigger after import?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to execute my trigger after import data to `MYTABLE`?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_class_id 
ON MYTABLE 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE MYTABLE 
    SET CLASS_ID = SUBSTRING(CLASS_NAME, 1, 4)
```

I have tried import with this trigger, but my `CLASS_ID` is not replaced with 4 first character from `CLASS_NAME`

But if I use `insert into ...` it's working (my trigger is executed)

Comment: Should the `CLASS_ID` field always hold the first 4 characters of `CLASS_NAME` or will it change later? If it's always to be those letters, you could use a calculated column instead.

Comment: what do you mean by import ? This trigger will always fire when a row is inserted in mytable so to answer your question all you need to do to execute this trigger is to insert a row into mytable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bulk-import operation should execute triggers only for a table with INSERT and INSTEAD OF triggers that support multiple row inserts.

If you are using **BCP** command for the import, you can explicitly invoke the trigger using the qualifier **-h "FIRE_TRIGGERS"**

Read more on this [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx)

There is no direct option in the import export wizard. One way is you can save the package created by the import export wizard then edit the packae ->Go to the Advanced Editor -> go to "FastLoadOptions" ->  Set FIRE_TRIGGERS flag to true.

if you excel data columns varies frequently,better option is to go with a ***BCP*** command with  qualifier **-h "FIRE_TRIGGERS"**

Comment: thanks @unnikrishnan, how to applied -h "FIRE_TRIGGERS" ?
i tried throw that to my trigger query, but its not working

sorry i don't understand with artikel on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx

thank you...

Comment: can i use -h "FIRE_TRIGGERS" when i import my data with sql server import and export wizard?

Comment: thanks for you solution, but i still don't understand how to use FIRE_TRIGGERS. i can't found `the packae ->Go to the Advanced Editor -> go to "FastLoadOptions" -> Set FIRE_TRIGGERS flag to true.`

Comment: i have the package created by the import export wizard, but i didn't know how go to the advanced editor and "fastloadoptions"

Comment: thank you very much @unnikrishan i can do it (im use visual studio for open advanced editor) :)

Comment: yes ..you have to open the package in visual studio for the advance editor.  Anyway you found it... great.. happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the data from inserted row.

So your query would look like

---

Update
MYTABLE 
SET 
  CLASS_ID = SUBSTRING(i.CLASS_NAME, 1, 4) from inserted i.

---

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: i want every i have a new data (import from excel), data on CLASS_ID replace with 4 character from class_name